# Changing 2D pointer in pascal

Tags: c, windows, pointers, pascal, fpc

How can I write equivalent to this in pascal?

```
void push(struct node **head, struct node **member)
{
  (*head)->next = *member;
  (*member)->prev = *head;
  (*member)->next = NULL;
  *head = *member;
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
procedure Push(head : nodeptr; prev : nodeptr; sym : nodeptr);
begin
    prev^.prev := sym;
    sym^.prev := prev;
    sym^.next := nil;
    prev := sym;
end;
```

In fact, I want to know how to do equivalent to this in pascal: `*head = *member;` where both are of `struct node**` type, 2D-pointer.

**EDIT:** I've added my pascal compiler. It might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this tutorial on pascal [pointer to pointer](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_pointer_to_pointer.htm), you could do something like this

```
program exPointertoPointers;
type
  iptr = ^integer;
  pointerptr = ^ iptr;
var
  num: integer;
  ptr: iptr;
  pptr: pointerptr;
  x, y : ^word;
begin
  num := 3000;
  (* take the address of var *)
  ptr := @num;
  (* take the address of ptr using address of operator @ *)
  pptr := @ptr;
  (* let us see the value and the adresses *)
  x:= addr(ptr);
  y := addr(pptr);
  writeln('Value of num = ', num );
  writeln('Value available at ptr^ = ', ptr^ );
  writeln('Value available at pptr^^ = ', pptr^^);
  writeln('Address at ptr = ', x^); 
  writeln('Address at pptr = ', y^);
end.
```

Comment: How do I assign a `x` of pointer to record type to a `y` pointer-to-pointer to recored type? I tried `x^.m := y^;` in C it's `x->m = *y` where it's declared as `struct node *x, **y;`

Comment: I think you're looking for `x^.m := @y;`

Comment: I forget to mentioned I've tried this too. I got got "nodeptr" expected "node"

Comment: where is m define? Make sure it's of type `^ptr`.

Comment: `m` is a member of record of `^ptr1` type that's a pointer to recored itself: `type ptr1 = ^foo; ptr2 = ^ptr1; foo = record m : ptr1;`. In this case: `x^.m := y^; ` x is `ptr1` and `y` of `ptr2`.

Comment: Will not this make `m` and 2D pointer? isn't what I'm looking for, but set a value from a 2D pointer to apointer.

Comment: Error: Incompatible types: got "ptr1" expected "foo"

Comment: `ptr1` is the exact type of `m`. Is this a Pascal's thing or a compiler bug?

Comment: Where did "foo" come from? It's probably not a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do a pointer to a pointer like so:

```
type
   ptr = ^integer;
   ptr_ptr = ^ ptr;
```

And then deference it like so:

```
ptr_ptr ^^
```

Therefore `*head = *member;` should probably look like `head^^ := member^^`.